# How to disable warning in Nim

Tags: exception, nim-lang

I'm trying to suppress this warning:

```
Warning: inherit from a more precise exception type like ValueError, IOError or OSError. If these don't suit, inherit from CatchableError or Defect. [InheritFromException]
```

And I tried this:

```
type
  ReturnException* = ref object of Exception {.warning[InheritFromException]:off.}
  value*: BaseType
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this:

```
type
  ReturnException* = ref object of CatchableError
```

or :

```
type
  ReturnException* = ref object of Defect
```

The difference is that a `CatchableException` can be caught by `try/except`, while a `Defect` always causes the program to exit.

Answer (score 2):

The warning pragma is a switch that turns on and off. So you need to do something like this:

```nim
{.warning[InheritFromException]:off.}
type
  ReturnException* = ref object of Exception
  value*: BaseType
{.warning[InheritFromException]:on.}
```